# DAX - Plot Previous working day value against today's date

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table like this,

```
ReportingDate  ReportingDateOrder   Status     Customer
01/06/2021        1                  Active    Present
01/06/2021        1                  Active    
01/06/2021        1                  Inactive  Present
27/05/2021        2                  Inactive  Present
27/05/2021        2                  Active    Present
27/05/2021        2                  Active    Present
26/05/2021        3                  Active    Present
```

I want to generate an visual table like this,

```
ReportingDate         PreviousDaySales 
01/06/2021                        2
27/05/2021                        1
26/05/2021                        0
```

The logic for previousdaysales is the count of active lines for the previous available reporting date.

This is what I have tried so far, but it is returning empty.

```
PreviousDaySales = 

var selectedreportingdate = SELECTEDVALUE('Table1'[Reporting Date])

var selectedreportingrank = CALCULATE(MIN('Table1'[ReportingDateOrder]),FILTER('Table1', 'Table1'[Reporting Date] = selectedreportingdate))

var old_rank = selectedreportingrank + 1

var val1 = CALCULATE(COUNT('Table1'[Action Status]),  FILTER('Table1', 'Table1'[Status] = "Active" && 'Table1'[ReportingDateOrder] = old_rank))

return val1
```

Kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
CurrentActiveLines := 
CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(RStatus),RStatus[Status]="Active")

PreviousReportingDateActiveLines := 
VAR CurrentDate = SELECTEDVALUE( RStatus[ReportingDate] )
VAR PreviousDate = 
CALCULATE(
    LASTDATE( RStatus[ReportingDate] ),
    RStatus[ReportingDate] < CurrentDate
    )
VAR Result = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS( RStatus ),
    RStatus[ReportingDate] = PreviousDate,
    RStatus[Status] = "Active"
    )
RETURN
Result
```